# Intent Service never getting called

Tags: android, service, android-intent

I am trying out Intent services. This is what I use to call it

```
    Button updateLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateLocation);
        updateLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent updateLocIntent=new Intent(ImTracking.this,UpdateLocation.class);
                startService(updateLocIntent);}});
```

However in my UpdateLocation class, it never hits any of my break points.

```
    public class UpdateLocation extends IntentService{

    public UpdateLocation() {
        super("UpdateLocation");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);
                final String id = prefs.getString("ID", "");
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://iphone-radar.com/gps/gps_locations");

                JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
...
```

What is going on?

Thanks

PS. I am using this because I want to call it with an alarm manager. However on button click I would like to show a progress dialog, where would I place the progress dialog for an intent service? (I've only had experience working with async tasks so far)

Comment: I'm no expert on this but don't you have to register your receiver AND set a filter for the particulat intent you wish to capture? When I've done this I did it in code but I think it can be done in the Manifest/xml too

Comment: could you show me an example? Im not quite sure what you mean by filter

Comment: Sometimes you have given wrong `android:name` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, It may without package name

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Did you [declare your service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Declaring) in `AndroidManifest.xml`? It won't be invoked unless it's declared like this:

```
<manifest ... >
  ...
  <application ... >
      <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The name is relative to the `package` defined in the manifest tag. If your manifest tag has `package` defined as `com.example` and your service is in `com.example.data` then the name of the service will need to be `.data.ExampleService`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the line below will allow you to step through the service.  Make sure to remove it when you aren't debugging. If you don't the processing of your service will stop at that point and won't continue.

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

Comment: do i put this line before or after startservice?

Comment: it goes inside of your IntentService.  Place it right before your breakpoint or at the beginning of onHandleIntent()